# Facilidades para o cliente, WCF ou Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, wcf, asp.net-web-api

Preciso criar um **serviço Web** para inserção de dados em uma base que necessita de validação para garantir a integridade dos dados.

Tenho como requisito, facilitar a utilização dos meus "clientes". Sendo assim, devo optar por WCF (SOAP) ou Web API (Rest)?

Answer (score 2):

As duas tecnologias podem ajudá-lo. Na minha opinião, você deve optar pela tecnologia que esteja mais próxima dos seus conhecimentos.

Por exemplo,
WEB API suporta apenas HTTP. Já WCF suporta vários outros protocolos como, por exemplo, http, TCP e UDP. Existem outras diferenças que devem ajudá-lo na escolha.

Este artigo pode ajudá-lo.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ainda que o artigo seja interessante, não era uma melhor ideia fazer uma pequena transcrição com os pontos importantes de forma a que quem veja a pergunta não ficar sem resposta caso o link esteja inactivo?

Answer (score 2):

Como sempre, a resposta é "depende". O que você quer dizer por "facilitar" os clientes? Que funcionalidades são necessárias para o serviço? Como o serviço será exposto, principalmente em relação a questões de segurança?

WCF (ou alguma outra alternativa SOAP) tem a vantagem de que é relativamente fácil criar um *proxy* (uma classe com métodos equivalentes às operações do serviço) que o cliente pode usar para chamar o serviço. Se você tem requisitos de segurança fortes (como autenticação de clientes via certificados) ou precisa de funcionalidades típicas de web services (como *reliable messaging*, *WS-Security*, etc.) então WCF deve ser uma opção melhor.

Web API, por default, não tem a facilidade de gerar um *proxy* para o cliente consumir o serviço, mas se isso é o único problema você pode providenciar um "SDK" (algumas classes utilitárias) que podem ser usadas pelo cliente para consumir o seu serviço. Como @Venatci mencionou, Web API suporta apenas HTTP, mas se é HTTP que você precisa, esse suporte é bem melhor que o WCF e você provavelmente irá implementar o serviço de forma mais eficiente. No entanto, para o cliente isso não deve fazer muita diferença (afinal de contas para o serviço - independente de ser WCF / Web API / outro - o "cliente" é apenas um grupo de bytes que está chegando no socket onde o serviço está funcionando.